# ##ISSUE: it showing $ node -v C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: linee

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, firebase, firebase-tools

After I install Firebase CLI using npm package `npm install -g firebase-tools` , When type firebase is showing

`$ firebase C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

So I tried upgrade the Node.js and I restarted the command it showing

`$ node -v C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found`

Kindly anyone resolve the issue PLEASE!!!!

I want to know where is the problem and what to do to rectify the issue?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions [in this thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29287#issuecomment-524859390)?